# 3D Fourier transforms of $e^{-\beta r} $ and $re^{-\beta r} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to find the integrals
$$\large\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-\beta \left|\vec{r}\,\right|}e^{i \vec{q} \cdot\,\vec{r}} \mathop{d^3r}$$

$$\large\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left|\vec{r}\,\right|e^{-\beta \left|\vec{r}\,\right|}e^{i \vec{q} \cdot\,\vec{r}} \mathop{d^3r}$$

Both integrated over all of $\mathbb{R}^3 $. These are essentially 3D Fourier transforms. Unfortunately the first factor looks nice in spherical coordinates, but not the second factor. I was able to integrate $e^{i \vec{q} \cdot\,\vec{r}} $ over the azimuthal angle using Mathematica, but it was not able to proceed integrating the polar angle. The actual integral I'm trying to solve is 
$$\large\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}_3} e^{-3 \left|\vec{r}\,\right|/(2 a)} \left(2-\frac{ \left|\vec{r}\,\right|}{a}\right)e^{i \vec{q}\, \cdot\, \vec{r}}\mathop{d^3r}$$

This appeared as part of a physics textbook problem, so I think this should somehow be doable.

Comment: Perhaps the thing to note is that the functions $e^{-\beta r}$ and $r e^{-\beta r}$ are symmetric. I may be able to simplify the problem by choosing the z axis to be in the direction of $\vec{q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting the Jacobian $r^2\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the polar angle and assuming that $|\mathbf{q}|=q$ is parallel to the polar direction
\begin{equation}
\int \exp(-\beta r)e^{i\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r}}d^3r
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\int_{r=0}^\infty r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin \theta d\theta
\exp(-\beta r)e^{iqr\cos\theta}
=2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty r^2 dr \int_0^\pi \sin \theta d\theta
\exp(-\beta r)e^{iqr\cos\theta}
\end{equation}
with $\cos\theta =z$, $dz=-\sin\theta d\theta$
\begin{equation}
=-2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty r^2 dr \int_{1}^{-1} dz
\exp(-\beta r)e^{iqrz}
\end{equation}
Substitute $t=iqrz$, $dz=dt/(iqr)$
\begin{equation}
=2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty r^2 dr \int_{-1}^1 dz
\exp(-\beta r)e^{iqrz}
=\frac{2\pi}{iq} \int_{r=0}^\infty r \exp(-\beta r)dr \int_{-iqr}^{iqr} dt
e^{t}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\frac{2\pi}{iq} \int_{r=0}^\infty r
\exp(-\beta r)[e^{iqr}-e^{-iqr}]dr
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\frac{4\pi}{q} \int_{r=0}^\infty r
\exp(-\beta r)\sin(qr) dr
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\frac{4\pi}{q} \frac{2\beta q}{(\beta^2+q^2)^2}
\end{equation}
...all very similar to 
[3D Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307019/3d-fourier-transform)